# WIX: Can't stop windows service during upgrade

Tags: winapi, service, wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I have two program versions:

- V0.0.1 - I work on Visual Studio 2005 and wix v3.5 to create a MSI installer.
- V0.0.2 - I work on Visual Studio 2013 and wix v3.9 to create a MSI installer.

In both versions I suppose to install a Windows services. The problem is that when I install V0.0.2 on top of V0.0.1 the V0.0.1's service doesn't stop and the installation ends with error. I'm pretty sure that the stop message is not sent at all from the V0.0.2's msiexec through controlservice(as far as I managed to debug it using Windbg).
Install V0.0.1 over V0.0.1 works fine and the stop message was sent successfully.

This is the code of ServiceControl from InstallationFiles.wxi. identical to both versions. Written with help of this site http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html

```
     <ServiceControl Id="MyService.exe.Control" Name="MyService" Remove="uninstall" Stop="both" Start="install" Wait="yes">
    <ServiceArgument>InstallerStart</ServiceArgument>
  </ServiceControl>
```

CustomAction is irrelevant in this case

Comment: As Chris says, you need to sow the components and make sure they are being installed, and show your ServiceInstall code too. It's not unusual for people to use one name in the ServiceInstall and another in ServiceControl, and that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the remove / stop / start on  install | uninstall | both refers to installation state of the component not the product.   I can't see what component / feature these elements are tied to but if those components aren't getting  installed as part of the upgrade then the stop won't occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't figure out how to check whether the component gets installed

Comment: Logging the upgrade would indicate.  You need to read up on such topics as Minor vs Major Upgrades and the Default File Versioning Rules. (MSDN topics)